# Win32 Encryption with the same size

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption, public-key-encryption

I want to encrypt an array of 15 byte. The problem is I want the cipher text to be of the same size.

What I did as

1. Make certificate: **makecert.exe -n "CN=me" -sv PrivateKey.pvk -pe Certificate.cer**
2. Write this code to import the certificate and then encrypt the plain text.

   ```
   BYTE    FileContent[1024];
   DWORD   dwActualFileLen = 0;
   HANDLE  hCertFile;
   if(CryptAcquireContext(&m_hCryptProv, NULL, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0))
   {
   hCertFile = CreateFileA("C:\\projects\\Certificate.cer", 
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ, 
        NULL, 
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        NULL);

   ReadFile(hCertFile, FileContent, 1024, &dwActualFileLen, NULL);

   m_CertContext = CertCreateCertificateContext(X509_ASN_ENCODING, FileContent, dwActualFileLen);

   CryptImportPublicKeyInfo(m_hCryptProv, X509_ASN_ENCODING, &m_CertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo, &m_hPubKey);
   }

   CryptEncrypt(m_hPubKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, tempBuffer, &dwNewLen, 128);
   ```

The cipher text is always 128 byte. I want to force it to be of the same size as the plain text.

Comment: the code seems a little bit weird but I extracted if from a class I am working on. so forget about the structure and error checking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSA algorithm can not output arbitrary sized ciphertext. You have to live with this. As your RSA keylen seems to be 1024 bits (128 bytes), input and output sizes are always 128 bytes, equal to the size of the RSA keylen...

Comment: I am encrypting in place and I can not wait to accumulate values of 128 byte. I have only 15 byte for each one.

Answer (score 1):

Far too complex. XOR the input string with a 15 byte key. This is known as an One Time Pad, and is provably 100% secure. Decrypting is the same as encrypting, `(a XOR b) XOR b = a` for all a and b, and `(a XOR b) XOR c = a` if and only if b=c.